# Clojure: serializing and parsing date/time to/from file?

Tags: datetime, clojure, jodatime, clj-time

I'd like to store some test data to a file and read it out again in my tests. The data is a sequence of Clojure maps, one property of which is a `clj-time` (`org.joda.time.DateTime`) date/time. When I write the value to the file (with `spit`), it serializes as `#<DateTime 2014-10-03T12:57:15.000Z>`. When I try to read it back (with `slurp`), I get:

```
RuntimeException Unreadable form  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

I guess that isn't surprising since without more information I don't see how it would know how to parse a `DateTime`. Is there some way to read these values and have them parsed properly or so I have to serialize them as strings and parse them manually when I read them back out?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the chronology field from `DateTime`? That will make your task much harder if you do.

Comment: Luckily we don't need this. It's just a testing fixture anyway so we can be quite specific about what we do and don't support.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure comes with a tagged reader for `java.util.Date`

```
user> (java.util.Date.)
#inst "2014-10-28T19:46:50.183-00:00"
user> (pr-str (java.util.Date.))
"#inst \"2014-10-28T19:47:00.503-00:00\""
user> (read-string (pr-str (java.util.Date.)))
#inst "2014-10-28T19:47:11.626-00:00"
```

one option would be to convert from `org.joda.time.DateTime` to `java.util.Date` before writing to file, and convert back again after reading.

```
user> (.toDate (org.joda.time.DateTime.))
#inst "2014-10-28T19:50:34.859-00:00"
user> (org.joda.time.DateTime. (.toDate (org.joda.time.DateTime.)))
#<DateTime 2014-10-28T12:51:09.231-07:00>
```

Comment: Is this better somehow than just storing them as strings? Ideally I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require pre/post-processing (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

@noisesmith's answer spurred me to research tagged readers in more detail (thanks @noisesmith!). It looks like https://gist.github.com/ragnard/4738185 will let me do what I want. Specifically, you can bind a new value to `*data-readers*` and tell the reader to parse the value any way you want.

In this case, I just want to read out my test data so I don't even need to modify the `print-method` and `print-dup` protocols. I just store the data as normal dates (`#inst "..."`) and the use the `with-joda-time-reader` macro to read them out.